# Stretch Webpage Height to Fit Browser

Tags: html, css

Been trying for ages now and can't work it out.

Here's the website http://www.connorhome.com/

Basically, if you view this site in a large browser window, a window which is longer than the height of the webpage then there is whitespace underneath. I want to continue the 'footer' div (the dark colour) to stretch to fit the browsers height. I've already tried min-height and height elements but can't get it to stretch.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the body to the colour of the dark colour :

As in (colour is not exact ) :

```
body {
   background-color: #ffff80;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was simple. You've saved me another few hours pulling my hair out, thanks very much!

Comment: @user113458 : Glad to be of assistance. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, if you please ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just checked out the website on my mac, the white space does appear on the bottom.

If you are happy with the positioning of the footer and only want to get rid of the white space at the bottom. Add this to your home class.

```
background-color:#231F20
```

The footer itself wont expand but it will appear that way to the end user

Comment: Thanks Adam I've sorted it now with both yours and Edelcom's advice.

Comment: not a problem I was typing the reply and only realised it was sorted when I posted.